# Message passing between two perl files

Tags: perl

I have 2 Perl files which cannot be merged and have to be run separately. My first file does certain initialization of parameters which are used by my second file, which performs some testing. Now I want to use the parameters initialized in the first file in the second file so how can I do that?

I will write a Perl script for Software testing. I need to write two files one is initialization file which will do all the initialization and the second file contains the test sequence to execute which will use initialize parameters. I need to run both files separately. Execution-wise my first file will execute first and then my second file will run.

I am thinking of using XML file where the first file will log the parameter in the file and the second file will get the parameters from that file? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Could you tell us more about your design? For instance, maybe designing your second file as a module and running its functions using threads could be an easier idea, but it's hard to know without more details about what you are actually doing.

Comment: Check https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable

Comment: If the two progs aren't guaranteed to be running at the same time (e.g. if the 1st launches the 2nd, or if the 2nd waits for input from the 1st via a socket or something), then you will necessarily need to store the data somewhere. /// Now, there are multiple options as to where the data can be stored. The two most common options that come to mind are file and database, but there are other options. And within each of these, there are multiple formats and options that can be used. Which is best is situational. /// This question is therefore too broad (too vague) and should be closed.

Comment: JSON, YAML, XML, Storable all have pros and cons.

Comment: Another possibility is that the second script runs the first one, and receives the parameters from it. This can go via first script's stdout, or pipes or sockets (or other IPC mechanisms).  What is best to do depends on details of course, of which none are given; the question is way too generic -- include some specifics if you'd like more specific responses.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the answer. I will write a Perl script for Software testing. I need to write two files one is initialization file which will do all the initialization and the second file contains the test sequence to execute which will use initialize parameters. I need to run both files separately. Execution-wise my first file will execute first and then my second file will run.@Dada

Comment: My first file does a lot of initialization for about 300 test case so which is a better option JSON or XML? @ikegami

Comment: You didn't actually explain anything (IMO). **Why** do your two scripts need to run separately? What can of initialization does the first script do? Why can't you use a module? Could you create a minimalist example where you reduce your scripts to just a few lines of code each, in order for us to get a better sense of your situation?

Answer (score 1):

If your initialization produces only plain key-value pairs then any way of serialising data will suffice. Otherwise `XML` is probably the worst option for your case. You might need to put a lot of effort to get the same data structure in your second script. This happens because by default xml modules do not know what should be an atrribute, a child node or an array of nodes. For example, passing a one-element array of hashes to xml from first script might turn to just a single hash in your second script. The results will highly depend on xml modules, options you pass to them and the data itself.

`JSON` should'n have such issues. It might have unnecessary type conversions but you shouldn't really notice them.

[Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) guarantees that you get the same data in your second script.

You might find [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to be an easier solution. But it has some security issues since you need to execute its output in your second script.

All of the above are not meant to be used with data containing self-references and anything but `scalars`, `arrayrefs` and `hashrefs`.